# Running jquery script triggered by context menu in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extension development. The sample code I have is not running properly.
Requirement: Executing any jquery script(say $("body").hide();) on click of context menu button.

From the code, only jquery part is not working.

I have following files:

manifest.json

```
 {
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "jQuery DOM",
"version": "1",
"permissions": [
 "contextMenus","tabs","activeTab"
],
"background": {
 "scripts": ["jquery.min.js","sample.js"]
 },
 "description": "Manipulate the DOM when the page is done loading",
 "browser_action": {
 "name": "Manipulate DOM",
 "icons": ["icon.png"],
 "default_icon": "icon.png"
 },
 "content_scripts": [ {
  "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "background.js" ],
  "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
 }]
 }
```

background.js

```
 $("body").append('Test');
```

I have icon.png in folder, and it gets loaded well.
jquery.min.js in same folder

sample.js

```
            alert("Extension loaded");
            function genericOnClick(info, tab) {
            alert("Tab "+tab.id);
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                    file: "jquery.min.js",
                    allFrames: true
                },function(){
                alert("callback");
                  $("body").hide();
                });
            alert("Completed");
            $("body").hide();
            }
            var contexts = ["page"];

            for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
              var context = contexts[i];
              var title = "Test Page menu item";
              var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                                   "onclick": genericOnClick});
              console.log("'" + context + "' item:" + id);
            }
```

background.js works!
All the alerts work file, but .hide function from genericOnClick doesn't work.
Even if I move the code from sample.js to backgroud.js, it won't work.
Can you please tell me where did i go wrong ?

Comment: It looks like you're combining a content script (run in every page's context) with a background script (runs in chrome's context on every page) with a browser action (runs when you click the action's icon).  What are you trying to do, and when do you want it to happen?

Comment: I want that $("body").hide() should work when i click context menu item.

Comment: Everything looks ok to me, except that background scripts (`sample.js`) aren't allowed to interact with the DOM.  I think you'll need to message your content script (`background.js` -- should be renamed), and have that hide the body.  And you wouldn't need the browser action.  Does that take care of things?

Comment: @Teepeemm I tried preparing the context menu with action, but these menus with action aren't working in backgroud.js. Forgive me for file naming, it creates confusion. Regarding browser action, it is there (for me atleast) to test if add-on works. there is no action written on it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, a background script isn't allowed to interact with the DOM, (while a content script isn't allowed to use  `chrome.contextMenus`).  You need to combine both, and use message passing to tell the content script when to execute.  Some other adjustments I made:

- I renamed `background.js` and `content.js` so that their names now
  reflect what they do, and made `background.js` into an event page.
- I removed the browser action (the
  extension would need `browserAction.html` or `background.js` would
  need `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` to do anything
  other than show the icon).
- Programmatically injecting jquery means that always loading it as a
  content script is unnecessary (although skipping programmatic injection allows you to omit the last three permissions).
- `background.js` doesn't need jquery
  anymore, so it isn't loaded there either.
- The default `executeScript`
  tab is the active tab, so we don't need it's id.

Here's the finished product:

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "jQuery DOM",
  "version": "1",
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus", "activeTab", "tabs", "http://*/", "https://*/"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "content.js" ],
    "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
  }],
  "description": "Manipulate the DOM when the page is done loading"
}
```

`background.js`

```
function genericOnClick(info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                              {"file": "jquery.min.js"},
                              function() {
                                  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{"message":"hide"});
                              });
}


chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Test Page menu item",
                            "contexts":["page"],
                            "id":"contextId"});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(genericOnClick);
```

`content.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.message == 'hide') {
        $("body").hide();
    }
    sendResponse();
});
```

Your `content.js` is probably much larger than it is here (+1 for the [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)).  But if it is small, another option would be to omit the content script entirely, and replace the `sendMessage` with `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"$('body').hide();"});`.

Comment: Or if `content.js` is gigantic, programmatically inject it as well as `jquery`, and still omit the `content_scripts` object from `manifest.json`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it worked. I went ahead with my requirement of running same script on about:blank page, but it has failed. Could you please provide your suggestion on solution to my question. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917727/chrome-extension-to-execute-jquery-script-on-aboutblank-page for more detail